# What is the result of gitlab-ci-runner and what gets uploaded?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am preparing for gitlab-ci setup but I've reached 2 questions that I can not find answer to:

1) If there is no support for artifacts on Windows (using shell executor), what will be uploaded after build script finishes?

2) Are artifacts the right way to tell the runner what should be uploaded? Or is it only something extra to tell the runner that some generated garbage might be interesting so it would be nice to upload it beside the true result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify artifacts nothing will get uploaded automatically. You will only see the build log.

E.g. if you use the docker runner the entire container will be removed after the build finishes. The runner will upload your artifacts to gitlab and that is it.

Obviously you are free to copy/upload any asset during the build as you see fit.